# Undefined Json in react

Tags: json, reactjs

I have (hopefully) a short question.
I want to display values out of a json file in react. 
Here is my code for the readJson.js file and the readJsonChild.js file.
readJsons.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyAppChild from './readJsonChild.js';
import * as data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
      var json2 = data         
      var arr = [];
      Object.keys(json2).forEach(function(key) {
        arr.push(json2[key]);
      });
      return <ul>{arr.map(item => <MyAppChild key={item.Name} Name={item.Name} Roughness={item.Roughness} Thickness={item.Thickness} />)}</ul>;
    }
  }
```

readJsonChild.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyAppChild extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <li>{this.props.Name + " - " + this.props.Roughness + " - " + this.props.Thickness}</li>;

    }
  }
```

My Json looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "Material":{
        "Name":"Test ",
        "Roughness":"12 ",
        "Thickness":"4234 ",
        "Conductivity":" ",
        "Specific Heat":" ",
        "Thermal Absorptance":" ",
        "Solar Absorptance":" ",
        "Visible Absorptance":" "
        }
    }
]
```

If I run the code I get three undefind values on the front end.
If I integrate the JSON code directly into the readJson file it works.
So, where is the problem?

Comment: Add `console.log()` statements to see what `json2` and `arr` look like.

Comment: From where do you plan to fetch `json`? It appears that your json is data. Where does that come from?

Comment: do we need need to write export statement in Material.json ?

Comment: Hi AKX. If a add consoloe.log(json2) and console.log(arr) I get the object/arry with the values I want. But ony in the console. I can't display the values in the front end. Strange!

Comment: I think I can load the json via import * as data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json'; You can have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var json2 = data;` should be `var json2 = data[0];`

Your `data` is an array of object, not object.

[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wj3m9j914).

By looking at your sample JSON file, you can write

```
import * as data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json';
```

as

```
import data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json';
```